# Run bash command with json parameters from jq

Tags: bash, json

How can I run a bash command for every json object in a json array using jq? So far I have this:

```
cat credentials.json | jq -r '.[] | .user, .date, .email' | mycommand -u {user} -d {date} -e {email}
```

This doesn't seem to work. How can I take the parameters out of the json array into my command?

My json file looks something like this:

```
[
   "user": "danielrvt",
   "date": "11/10/1988",
   "email": "myemail@domain.com",
   ...
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an solution based on [my answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45943903/8379597) on Stack Overflow.

```
#!/bin/bash
json='
[
  {
   "user": "danielrvt",
   "date": "11/10/1988",
   "email": "myemail@domain.com"
  }, 
  {
   "user": "anotheruser",
   "date": "1/1/1970",
   "email": "anotheruser@domain.com"
  }
]
'

jq -M -r '
    .[] | .user, .date, .email
' <<< "$json" | \
while read -r user; read -r date; read -r email; do
   echo "$user $date $email"
done
```

Example output

```
danielrvt 11/10/1988 myemail@domain.com
anotheruser 1/1/1970 anotheruser@domain.com
```

In your case you could replace the use of `<<< "$json"` with `< credentials.json` and the `echo "$user $date $email"` with `mycommand -u "$user" -d "$date" -e "$email"` as appropriate but this should make clear the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a for loop, for example

```
#!/bin/bash

JSONARRAY=$(cat credentials.json | jq -r '.[] | .user, .date, .email' | mycommand -u {user} -d {date} -e {email} | grep -v "[\|]")
for line in $JSONARRAY; do
    some command
done
```